# Django - Submission form Ajax (Replacing Div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

Before i talk about my topic, i wanna say that my english is not good, but i can give you more details if that helps you.

I have two Div :

- Connexion form (email + password) from index.html
- The menu when the user is connected from header.html

When the user click on "Connect" The first Div should be replace by the second one which is in another page.

Here is the code. I'm a beginner in programmation but i tried many solutions on the web but it was not efficient enough ^^'

```
  $('#loginForm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      url:$(this).attr("header.html"),
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data){
        var url = 'header.html';
        $('#member-space').html(data);
        //$('#member-space').load(url + '#member-space');
        $('#loginForm').remove();
        console.log("success")
    },
     error: function(er) {  console.log("error");
    }
});
```

});

If you have some ideas about the code, I will be happy to learn it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `$(this).attr("header.html")` will look at your `<form>` tag and try to find an attribute like this `<form header.html="">` which obviously doesn't exist (because `.` is not valid).

You are probably looking for `<form action="header.html">` that is the `action` attribute of the form that is being submitted. That would be `$(this).attr("action")`.

Also, you don't seem to be POSTing any `data` to the server. Is that correct/intentional?

Finally, if you are using Chrome/Chromium, hit Ctrl+Shift+J to open the developer console and then click on the "Network" tab to see the network requests that are happening, what URLs are being called and what the HTTP responses are.

Comment: $(this).attr("header.html") will look at the <div> "#member-space" in "header.html". This div contains the menu that should replace the initial <form> in login.html. I see errors from Ctrl+Schift+J, i can edit my topic with those errors. I continue to read your answer.